# Do French/International chefs really use/talk about Fahrenheit instead of Celsius degrees?

Tags: language, french-cuisine, professional, united-states

Example: https://youtu.be/lVcTvHTn6Dw?t=325

This chef is very French, yet he talks about Fahrenheit. In France, which is in Europe, surely they use Celsius? He seems to "think" in American terminology, which I find puzzling. I really expected a French chef to be all about Celsius, kilograms and other typical European conventions/measurements. To be fair, I don't remember if I've heard him refer to "cups" or other American measurement units.

Comment: Well, as a YouTube chef I would imagine that he uses whatever units his target audience is most comfortable with. Since he's speaking English, he's likely not targeting a primarily French audience.

Comment: The only people who use degrees Fahrenheit are old people in the UK, Americans, and Liberia. Everyone else will have used SI units since birth so clearly he's addressing his Liberian and British septegenarian audience :)

Comment: He's an American TV chef (originally from France). He is obviously using Fahrenheit for his American audience. The French don't use the Fahrenheit scale at all, and neither does most of the world. Even here in the UK which took a bit longer to go metric, it's only old people who might still remember it. I'm in my 50s, and it's totally alien to me. I'd have to look up a conversion table online.

Comment: As @BillyKerr implies, °F in the UK isn't printed on cooking instructions (except very rarely) or oven controls.  It is sometimes included in recipe books, even modern ones

Comment: A lot of chefs also refer to gas marks.

Comment: The metric system was invented in France. The original weights and measures of the metric system is still present in the mesuem louve in Paris.

Comment: A lot of American cooks also use the metric system as it is very much suited to cooking.

Answer (score 7):

His target audience is American, hence the Fahrenheit reference. His other videos mention 'eggplant' and Thanksgiving.